# pattern matching on image

Tags: java

hii to all..
I want to match Pattern from image which  it hold
actually I have an color image..
and I converted it into black foreground and white background..
and i also found the positions of data which are on fore ground..
now i want to compare these founded data with some alphabets ..
by pattern matching..
how can i do it?..

Comment: Can you clear things giving an example of what you have on your image and what you need to match it against?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do things such as recognize an 'A' in the image, [artificial neural networks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_neural_network) can help you. You could try the MLP (Multi-Layer Perceptron).

Comment: What is MLP? can u tell me in detail plz

Comment: It's a kind of neural network, basically, a classifier. You can use it to do things like recognizing a character in an image, such as a identifying the number of a car tag based on it's picture. Google about "neural networks mlp". Once I did a Java implementation, but it was too buggy. :-)